# Sending php variable within onclick function argument in HTML not working within a loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Let me know where I'm wrong. I've been trying to send php variable within a onclick function argument but its not working. The argument is passed in InsertReply function.
Here is the code:

```
$sql22 = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE PostID=$id";
$count22=$conect->query($sql22);
if($count22->num_rows>0){               //If comments exist
while($row = $count22->fetch_array()){      //Fetching Comments
    $mail = $row['UserMail'];
    $comment = $row['Comment'];
    $comment_id = $row['ID'];
     echo "<br>";
     echo "<p>".$comment_id."</p>";
    // Reply input field starts 
    ?>
     <input type='text' name='reply' id='reply' placeholder='Enter Reply here' min='5' max='100' class='big-input' style='width:40%;margin-left:40px;margin-right:40px;'>
 <?php
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='mail' id='mail' value= '".$current_user."'/>";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='postid' id='postid' value= '".$id."'/>";
echo "<button class='btn btn-outline-info' onclick='InsertReply(<?php echo $comment_id ?>)'>Reply</button>";
}       
}
```

Here is the InsertReply Function:

```
function InsertReply(x) {
alert("Insert Reply Function Called! with comment id : " + x);
//Storing values in variables
var reply = document.getElementById("reply").value; 
var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
var p_id = document.getElementById("postid").value;
alert("Reply is "+reply);

alert("Reply will be added with Reply : " + reply + ", by : "+ mail + ", Post ID : " + p_id + " & Comment ID : "+x);
```

I know there are lots of issues with the code. Please guide me as I'm badly stuck. Let me know if anything else is required. I just want to send variable value to the InsertReply function. Any alternate method or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "<button class='btn btn-outline-info' onclick='InsertReply(<?php echo $comment_id ?>)'>Reply</button>";
```

You are already echoing it so pass the value like this

```
echo "<button class='btn btn-outline-info' onclick='InsertReply($comment_id)'>Reply</button>";
```

Comment: Now it is saying that the input field is empty, even when I entered the text

Comment: i posted the same answer earlier... this is sad

Comment: change`'InsertReply($comment_id)'` to `'InsertReply(\"$comment_id\")'>`

Comment: down vote is for invalid answers, this is not a race or competition, we all are here to help each other out. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but please don't downvote any other answer without any valid reason

Comment: If you can upvote my question, I can also be able to upvote your answers as right now my reputations are not enough. I'll upvote both of your answers @DanyalSandeelo

Comment: Yeah for sure @AayushGupta. Please if you can upvote mine so that I'm eligible for the upvote option

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo there's another issue I would like to discuss with you. Can we discuss in a separate window?

Comment: start the conversion,i will join it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `<php>` tag inside echo. change like this...

```
echo "<button class='btn btn-outline-info' onclick='InsertReply(".$comment_id.")'>Reply</button>";
```